# Phone is not detected in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, lg

I have an LG G2 that runs Android 4.2.2. I've done everything I can to make sure that it's in a proper position that I can run my Android app on it. However, each time I try to run my application, it doesn't detect my device.

I've done everything from going to LG's site and manually downloading the driver (it's also on the phone itself). I've enabled USB Debugging on my phone in developers mode, and I set android:debuggable = "true". I'm not sure if this means anything, but my phone is connected to my computer via MTP, and whenever I try to go into usb_drivers in my eclipse directory, my laptop automatically determines that all drivers are up to date.

I honestly do not know what's going on here. If it matters, I've set in my Run Configurations to ask me to pick the device, but all that comes up is the Emulator, not my phone itself. I've also tried two different USB cables. Is there something I'm missing here??

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: have you seen this: http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html ?

Comment: In my work I´ve got a Samsung ACE II and if you don't unlock the phone screen it wont appear on the Eclipse device picker dialog. I know that you´ve surely tried it with the phone unlocked but just in case.

Comment: @ArchiFloyd yeah i followed the steps as closely as possible but still...idk what's going on.

Comment: What is your minimum API level for the app, defined in your manifest?

Comment: @hichris123 my min sdk is 8 and my target sdk is 17

Comment: When you type "adb devices", does your device show up? (I'm assuming Windows, and to type that you need to open a command console)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you connect the phone to the computer it should bring up a screen with four different options of how to connect. You need to select internet connection and pick either of the two options (I chose Ethernet). After selecting one, it will pop up a little screen about trusting the computer. Accept it and it should then be recognized by Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

1. try to restart adb server
2. try to use wandoujia or something similar to install driver
3. try to restart your eclipse

Answer (score 0):

(if your Os is windows) Try this:

1. Go to ControlPanel -> DeviceManager
2. Open (Universal serial bus controller) node.
3. You should see an item marked wrong something like (USB Composite Device). select it, right click on it and the select update driver and then select (Search Automatically ...)
4. You probably need to plug out your phone from computer, plug it in again.
5. Don't forget to select the option (debugging mode) to true in your mobile phone.

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem. Installed Kies software, and it automatically installed all needed drivers. http://www.samsung.com/in/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/JSP

Answer (score -1):

Try this: 
In the left panel in eclipse i.e. in package explorer click on your main application folder. Then click on run in the panel above. Now you will be able to see two options. One is for the hardware device you are using and other for the emulator.

Try and report back